# Under the influence of an external horizontal force, when is the velocity of a pendulum Bob maximum?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

I was asked this question (see image below) in a test

[image]

The answer to this question is (A) 37° and the reasoning was:

> Speed of the Bob is maximum when the resultant of **F** and **mg** is opposite to the direction of Tension **T** in the string at a point.

Why is the speed of Bob maximum when the resultant of **F** and **mg** is opposite to the direction of Tension **T** in the string at a point. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The net force on the bob is the vector sum of the tension in the string $T$, the horizontal force $F$ and the vertical weight $Mg$. If this net force has a radial component (perpendicular to the string) then the bob will be accelerating or decelerating. But at its maximum speed the bob is neither accelerating not decelerating. Therefore the radial force on it at this point must be zero.

The tension $T$ has no radial component. So the bob reaches its maximum speed when the radial component of the vector sum of $F$ acting horizontally and $Mg$ acting vertically is zero i.e. when this vector sum is parallel to the string.

Comment: Ok so $a_T = 0$ because at max speed, $\frac{d|\vec v|}{dt} = 0$ , right ? So this would also mean that $a_T = 0$ at minimum speed as well ? $a_T$ is tangential acceleration

Comment: @Guri Almost. We should really talk about maximum and minimum *velocity* rather than speed, since radial velocity has a sign. This difference is important because the minimum *speed* is zero, but the minimum *velocity* is negative.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for your answer and time 